# Why do I get 'ResolveManifestFiles task failed' error when building a WPF app that references WinRT API?

Tags: wpf, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am working on a WPF app that I want to create for Windows 8. I followed steps mentioned in [Hansleman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToCallWinRTAPIsInWindows8FromCDesktopApplicationsWinRTDiagram.aspx) to make some manual modifications using WinRT functions in a WPF app. Everything worked well, until I tried to publish the app. When I clicked on publishing the app I got error "The 'ResolveManifestFiles' task failed unexpectedly. System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range."

Afterwards, it will produce the same error when attempting a simple solution build.

Even if you create a simple WPF project and add the references mentioned in blog to access WinRT functions and publish, this issue can be reproduced.

I think it would be common scenario to call WinRT functions from WPF and someone should have done it. Is anyone aware what should be done to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is an issue with ClickOnce Deploy when WPF app is using WinRT APIs. I tried deploying using "InstallShield Limited Edition Project" and it worked without any issue. Microsoft, you need to fix this!

Comment: I am struggling with the same problem at the moment. You still haven't find any solution to make it work with ClickOnce?

Comment: I was not able to call WinRT APIs from WPF because of this issue. I have not worked on the project since then. But on msdn thread someone claims that using this  http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SensorsAndLocation/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx library from WinRT calls resolved the issue for him. You can check it out.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately the sensor API is not what I need, I would like to use the package deployment API. Anyway, thanks for the info.

Comment: You can also refer to the link http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/874199/clickonce-resolvemanifestfiles-task-failed-when-using-windows-runtime. It has a good official solution for this.